# Rerun PHP Script without losing value stored on a variable

Tags: php, html

How can I execute a PHP script a second time with the same values that were stored in my PHP variables the first time it was ran?

For example:
HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="php\test.php">
<input type="text" name="length" />
<input type="submit" value="Run again!" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

php\test.php:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
$length = $_POST['length'];
echo $length;
?>
<form method="POST" action="php\test.php">
<input type="submit" value="Run again!" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I make the button run the script again without losing the value in 'length' that was inputted in the text box? When I click the button I get an error saying cannot find 'length'.

Thanks!

Comment: Oops. There is also a submit button on the HTML form.

Comment: you know, you can edit your question ;)

Comment: Use $_SESSIONS for multi-step forms

Answer (score 2):

Put your variables in hidden inputs:

```
<input type="hidden" name="myvariable" value="value-from-first-run">
```

or use session to.

PS: fix your `action`. You should use `/` not `\`, even on windows.

Comment: Remember that a user (who has sufficient knowledge of the web) can change the values of hidden inputs.

Comment: This doesn't work either. It says Undefined index: 'length'.

Comment: What would be a better alternative to hidden inputs?

Comment: Session as user is unable to fake these values nor it is able to see them, so theoretically you can put whatever you want there and stay on safe ground (some precautions have to be made to disallow session cookie hijacking etc, but you can find more readings on that subject on web so if unsure - go for session

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is print the value of the length parameter inside the input HTML field:

```
php\test.php:
<html>
<body>
<?php
$length = $_POST['length'];
echo $length;
?>
<form method="POST" action="php\test.php">
<input type="submit" value="Run again!" />
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $length?>" name="length" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Ideally you should be validating the post data to ensure you don't get any nasty surprises.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend storing them in `$_SESSION`. If that won't work my store them in a database?

Answer (score 0):

Put your variables in hidden input fields:

```
<input type="hidden"
       name="length"
       value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['length']); ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

You store length in $_SESSION. Like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
session_start();

//  First form
$form1 = '<form method="post" action="">
<input type="text" name="length" />
<input type="submit" value="Run again!" />
</form>';

// Resend form
$form2 = '<form method="POST" action="">
<input type="submit" value="Run again!" />
</form>';

if (isset($_POST['length'])) {
    $length = $_SESSION['length'] = $_POST['length'];
    print $length . '<br>';
    print $form2;
} else if (isset($_SESSION['length'])){
    $length = $_SESSION['length'];
    print $length . '<br>';
    print $form2;
} else {
    print $form1;
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: mate it gives you undefined index if you run that page directly without coming from any form post. In your question there were two pages. Anyways, it seems you want a one page form. Check my edited post!